# How to get demographics of a business instagram profile without Auth token

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Is there any process line to extract the demographics of the instagram business profile. As a reference, i am looking to get similar response for a business profile that is generated through "https://api.grin.co/". It includes the engagement rates, impression rate, reach, video views, likes count, dislike count, audience segregation, and other demographics.

For this, is there any API or source that can help in getting this statistics?

Answer (score 0):

Instagram's API requires an access token to be provided for any requests made to their platform, including those for demographic data. An access token is a unique identifier that grants permission to access specific parts of the Instagram API. Therefore, it is accessible to either the account owner or any third-party applications to which the account has granted authorization. You can find more about it in their [official doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights#sample-demographic-metric-request)

Getting data and those integrations has some challenges, especially managing users access token, updating data frequently to recieve any updates, e.t.c.